# fputcsv creates one more space with space

Tags: php, csv

I have below code in my script.

```
    $file= fopen("./test.csv","x+");
    $proj_lists="name,age,address,city name,country name\n";
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$proj_lists),',',' ');
    fclose($file);
```

It creates a csv file with the given values.
My problem here is it creates extra space with double word.
Example "country name" is written as "country  name"(2 spaces in this word).

How to resolve this.

Comment: Though it is not totally clear what is going on some hints: remove that trailing line break from `$proj_lists`, it does not make any sense and may well cause issues in a line based process. Next replace that enclosing character you chose (the blank) with something else that makes sense, or leave it away. Try again and report back.

Comment: When I remove that en closer it adds double quotes. Output: name,age,address,"city name","country name"

Comment: I removed line break also

Comment: Sure, the `"` is the default enclosing character. Question is what you want, you certainly do _not_ want a blank...

Comment: I want the string as it is. In my first try it adds extra space with multiple string.In my second try no extra space but it adds double quotes

Comment: Ah, and now I actually understand what is happening: Since you chose the blank as enclosing character but also use a blank inside your tokens (words), you have a collision. The idea of auch an enclosing character around tokens is that it is clear where the token is delimited, actually. So somehow there has to be made a difference between the blanks in the tokens and those used as enclosing characters. That is done by "escaping" the contained blanks, here by using the additional blank. Not that intelligent in this case, indeed, but in the end it is you who said to insert that second blank.

Comment: Sorry I got it from some other post

Comment: Last parameter should be single letter length or should not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to work with `fputs()` like below:-

```
<?php
    $file= fopen("./test.csv","x+");
    $proj_lists=explode(',',"name,age,address,city name,country name");
    fputs($file,implode($proj_lists, ','));
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Output:- `name,age,address,city name,country name`

Comment: Before and end of the string shows space.  city name ,

Comment: Using `fputs` is not a replacement for `fputcsv` in the way you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem here is it creates extra space with double word

That's because you chose to use a space as the string enclosure character (4th argument, default value is a double quote). Here's the first line of the output:

```
name,age,address, city  name , country  name
                 ^    ^^    ^ ^       ^^
                 e    ee    e e       ee
```

Where `e` is the enclosure, and `ee` is the escaped enclosure, which is the escape character followed by the enclosure character (which happens to be part of the data you're trying to output).

It's best to simply use the defaults that come with `fputcsv`; that is, call the function with only two arguments.

```
fputcsv($file, explode(',', $proj_lists));
```

Which will output what most spreadsheet applications can read:

```
name,age,address,"city""name","country name
"
```